# Creating Bash Script to retrieve data from XML file

Tags: xml, linux, bash

I have an XML File like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<List>
    <Job id="1" name="John/>
    <Job id="2" name="Zack"/>
    <Job id="3" name="Bob"/>
</List>
```

I want to create a bash script where it pulls the id number from a specific name. For example, requesting John will out put 1. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

When parsing XML files, use a tool that *understands* xml.  You could use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

For example, saying:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/List/Job[@name=\"John\"]/@id" file.xml
```

would produce

```
1
```

BTW, your input isn't well-formed.  You have a missing quote in

```
<Job id="1" name="John/>
```

It should be

```
<Job id="1" name="John"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
#!/bin/bash

name="$1"
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ "name=\"$name\"" ]] && [[ $line =~ "Job id=\""([^\"]+) ]] &&  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < file
```

e.g. If `file` is your xml and John is fixed.

```
> ./abovescript John
1
> ./abovescript Zack
2
> ./abovescript Bob
3
```