# Creating bash script to parse xml file to csv

Tags: xml, linux, bash, csv

I'm trying to create a bash script to parse an xml file and save it to a csv file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <List>
    <Job id="1" name="John/>
    <Job id="2" name="Zack"/>
    <Job id="3" name="Bob"/>
</List>
```

I would like the script to save information into a csv file as such:

```
John | 1
Zack | 2
Bob  | 3
```

The name and id will be in a different cell.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Might have just edited the old question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21495533/3076724) rather than posting a new one, but you should definitely at least link to it when posting similar questions.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368347/convert-xml-file-to-csv-in-shell-script

Answer (score 5):

You've posted a query similar to your [pervious one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495533/creating-bash-script-to-retrieve-data-from-xml-file).  I'd again suggest using a XML parser.  You could say:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //List/Job -v @name -o "|" -v @id -n file.xml
```

It would return

```
John|1
Zack|2
Bob|3
```

for your sample data.

Pipe the output to `sed`: `sed "s/|/\t| /"` if you want it to *appear* as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ "name=\""(.*)"\"" ]] && name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" && [[ $line =~ "Job id=\""([^\"]+) ]] &&  echo "$name | ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < file
```

The line with `John` is malformed. With it fixed, example output

```
John | 1
Zack | 2
Bob | 3
```

Comment: in this instance `name="John/>`, there is no double quota after John, so recommend to replace `[[ $line =~ "name=\""(.*)"\"" ]]` to `[[ $line =~ "name=\""([^\"|/]*) ]]`

Comment: @BMW Thanks. I assumed it shouldn't be malformed xml, but if it is could do that or something like `([A-Za-z]*)`

Comment: dude, can u elaborate on that short script? I am quite confused. :) nevertheless its looking crazy good.

Answer (score 2):

Extending xmlstarlet approach:

Given this xml file as input:

```
<DATA>
  <RECORD>
    <NAME>John</NAME>
    <SURNAME>Smith</SURNAME>
    <CONTACTS>
      "Smith" LTD,
      London, Mtg Str, 12,
      UK
    </CONTACTS>
  </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

And this script:

```
xmlstarlet sel -e utf-8 -t \
  -o "NAME, SURNAME, CONTACTS" -n \
  -m //DATA/RECORD \
  -o "\"" \
  -v $"str:replace(normalize-space(NAME), '\"', '\"\"')" -o "\",\"" \
  -v $"str:replace(normalize-space(SURNAME),      '\"', '\"\"')" -o "\",\"" \
  -v $"str:replace(normalize-space(CONTACTS), '\"', '\"\"')" -o "\",\"" \
  -o "\"" \
  -n file.xml
```

You'll have the following output:

```
NAME, SURNAME, CONTACTS
"John", "Smith", """Smith"" LTD, London, Mtg Str, 12, UK"
```

Comment: This is a good solution, and elegant. Just I got: 

compilation error: element with-param
XSLT-with-param: Failed to compile select expression 'str:replace'

because of unclosed parenthesis in normalize-space call; should read "str:replace(normalize-space(NAME)  , '\"', '\"\"')"

Comment: Thanks for this.  Anyone else extracting URLs from XML may find the `&amp;` isn't escaped.  Fix this by adding `-T` after the `sel` command, e.g. `xmlstarlet sel -T -e utf-8......` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255304/unescape-the-ampersand-via-xmlstarlet-bugging-amp)

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed -nr 's/.*id=\"([0-9]*)\"[^\"]*\"(\w*).*/\2 | \1/p' file
```

Additional, base on BroSlow's cript, I merge the options.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ id=\"([0-9]+).*name=\"([^\"|/]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]} | ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < file
```