# Unescape the ampersand (&) via XMLStarlet - Bugging &amp;

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, wget, xmlstarlet

This a quite annoying but rather a much simpler task. According to this [guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html), I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash

content=$(wget "https://example.com/" -O -)
ampersand=$(echo '\&')

xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@id="table"]/tbody' - <<<"$content" 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet sel -t \
        -m "/tbody/tr/td" \
            -o "https://example.com" \
            -v "a//@href" \
            -o "/?A=1" \
            -o "$ampersand" \
            -o "B=2" -n \
```

I successfully extract each link from the table and everything gets concatenated correctly, however, instead of reproducing the **ampersand** as **&** I receive this at the end of each link:

```
https://example.com/hello-world/?A=1\&amp;B=2
```

But actually, I was looking for something like:

```
https://example.com/hello-world/?A=1&B=2
```

The idea is to escape the character using a backslash `\&` so that it gets ignored. Initially, I tried placing it directly into `-o "\&" \` instead of `-o "$ampersand" \` and removing `ampersand=$(echo '\&')` in this case scenario. Still the same result.

Essentially, by removing the backslash it still outputs:

```
https://example.com/hello-world/?A=1&amp;B=2
```

Only that the `\` behind the `&amp;` is removed.

Why?

I'm sure it is something basic that is missing.

Comment: To improve the quality of your answers, you should include some sample input along with the desired output, so we can test possible solutions.

Comment: Your are right. I'll follow your advice! Cheers @TomFenech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't reproduce your result but why don't make substitutions? Just filter your results through

```
sed 's/\\&amp;/\&/g'
```

add it to your pipe. It should replace all &amp; to &.

Comment: Hi @vollitwr I think you should remove `**`at the end, otherwise I think piping this `sed 's/\\&amp;/\&/g'` works the best here.

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed. It was remains of Stackoverflow formatting.

Answer (score 6):

`&amp;` is the correct way to print `&` in an XML document, but since you just want a plain URL your output should not be XML.  Therefore you need to switch to text mode, by passing `--text` or `-T` to the `sel` command.

Your example input doesn't quite work because example.com doesn't have any `table` elements, but here is a working example building links from `p` elements instead.

```
content=$(wget 'https://example.com/' -O -)
xmlstarlet fo --html <<<"$content" |
    xmlstarlet sel -T -t \
        -m '//p[a]' \
            --if 'not(starts-with(a//@href,"http"))' \
              -o 'https://example.com/' \
            --break \
            -v 'a//@href' \
            -o '/?A=1' \
            -o '&' \
            -o 'B=2' -n
```

The output is

```
http://www.iana.org/domains/example/?A=1&B=2
```

Comment: Hi @npostavs, it simplifies my script really well. The `--if` in my case is redundant because all the links to be extracted are missing the base url. Elsewise, it works great. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As you have already seen, backslash-escaping isn't the solution here. I can think of two possible options:

Extract the hrefs (probably don't need to be using *both* `xmllint` and `xmlstarlet` to do this), then just use a standard text processing tool such as `sed` to add the start and the end:

```
sed 's,^,https://example.com/,; s,$,/?A=1\&B=2,'
```

Alternatively, pipe the output of what you've currently got to `xmlstarlet unesc`, which will change `&amp;` into `&`.

Comment: Hi @TomFenech piping `xmlstarlet unesc` worked for me. Thanks!