# XMLStarlet remove last -n (newline) using Sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, xmlstarlet

This is a rather more simpler task which has been troubling me for some time. I have the following:

```
homepage=$(curl "https://example.com/")

xmlstarlet --quiet fo --html <<<"$homepage" |
xmlstarlet sel -T -t \
    -m "//*[@id='financial']/tbody/tr/td" \
        --if 'not(starts-with(a//@href,"http"))' \
          -o 'https://example.com' \
        --break \
        -v 'a//@href' \
        -o '/?start=1' \
        -o '&' \
        -o 'end=2' -n | \ 
            sed '${/^$/d;}' \ 
                >> "results.txt"
```

What I want to do is remove the last **newline** produced by `xmlstarlet` in `-o 'end=2' -n | \`. When it reaches the end if the link list it still produces a `-n` (newline) as if it where to continue adding more links, but actually I want to avoid the last `-n` instance respective to the last `href`.

My `sed '${/^$/d;}' \` that should do this returns the following error:

```
sed: ${/^$/d;}: No such file or directory
sed:  : No such file or directory
```

It somehow does not pipe the previous `STDOUT` to the `sed` `STDIN` correctly. In one of my prior [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255304/unescape-the-ampersand-via-xmlstarlet-bugging-amp) I worked with something similar and this `sed` command worked for me earlier:

```
sed 's/\\&amp;/\&/g'
```

On the other hand, I also tried using:

```
# The -e flag
sed -e '${/^$/d;}'
```

Which did not work for me either.

Can this be done directly from XMLStarlet without having to add an extra `sed` pipe?

What is wrong with my `sed`? What is the correct `sed` method?

Comment: Remove all whitespaces after \

Comment: Hi @Cyrus I don't completely understand. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable) I found that `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'` should remove the trailing whitespace. This, however, does not remove the **newline** after the last URL. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: Your code contains these two lines: `-o 'end=2' -n | \ ` and `sed '${/^$/d;}' \ `. Both contain a whilespace after the \. Remove those whitespaces.

Comment: That did the trick @Cyrus . Now the `sed` doesn't return `No such file or directory`, however, it still doesn't remove the trailing **newline**. I have a similar issue to this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228505/how-to-delete-the-newline-before-eof-in-a-text-csv-file-via-bash), whenever I execute `printf "%s" "$(</results.txt)" > results.txt` after my initial `XMLStarlet` script finishes, it does actually remove the last newline. This is an extra step which I would like to omit. I try to pipe `printf '%s'`, but the file is empty. I also tried `sed '$d'`, but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing this at the end of the script worked for me:

```
printf "%s" "$(</results.txt)" > results.txt
```

I was looking for doing this directly in XMLStarlet, hence this is a provisional answer.